# Запись массива php в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток.
Имеется массив переданный на страницу как `$_POST['ch']`, в котором храниться неизвестное количество чисел (`id checkbox'ов`). Есть таблица `base`, с столбиками `id` `name` `prod` `price`. И есть еще отдельная таблица `ord` с столбиками `id` `name` `prices` `sum`. Как сделать так, что-бы все числа, которые в массиве были `id` от таблицы `base` и в таблицу `ord` записывались значения:
`id` - авто;
`name` - здесь будут через запятую все числа с массива `$_POST['ch']`
`prices` - здесь через запятую все значения колонки `price` таблицы `base` (все числа с массива `$_POST['ch']` - это `id` таблицы `base`)
`sum` - сумма всех чисел с колонки `prices` (выше).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хранить что-то через запятую плохая практика, лучше создайте ещё одну таблицу, где будет построчно хранится `$_POST['ch']` и id записи к которой каждый элемент принадлежит.

Answer (score 1):

Заведите третью таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE it_to_name(
    id INT,
    name INT,
    price INT
)
```

Сделайте `id` внешним ключом к `id` из таблицы `ord`и храните в ней необходимые данные таким образом

```
  id  |  name  | price
------+--------+-------
   1  |   2    | 10000
   1  |  15    |  5000
   1  |  23    |  6350
   2  |  17    | 15000
   2  |  18    |   460
```

Answer (score 0):

Только не база данных `base` и `ord`, а, видимо, таблицы `base` и `ord` в БД.
Если предположить, что БД у нас MySQL, то код будет таким:

```
$join = join($_POST['ch'], ', '); //склеиваем массив в строку

$q="INSERT INTO `ord` (`name`,`prices`,`sum`) SELECT '$join' AS `name`, GROUP_CONCAT(`price` SEPARATOR ', ') AS `prices`, SUM(`price`) AS `sum` FROM `ord` WHERE `id` IN ($join)"; //создаём запрос
/*
далее надо выполнить в БД наш запрос $q,
например, функцией mysqli_query()
*/
```

**Важно!** Предполагается, что массив `$_POST['ch']` является "чистым", т.е. автор **уверен**, что в нём именно числа, а не что-то ещё. В противном случае надо предварительно проверить массив, иначе есть риск SQL-инъекции

Comment: еще бы не мешало добавить, что запись связей многие-ко-многим в виде строкового массива чаще всего кроме проблем ничего не добавляет. Это на порядок усложняет поиски и фильтрацию и не обеспечивает целостность данных в БД.

Comment: Если в массиве должны приходить только id (целые числа), то можно просто сделать `join(array_map('intval', $_POST['ch']), ', ')` - и инъекция уже невозможна будет. Можно еще даже array_unique туда накрутить (ну на всякий случай, для экономии).

Comment: Да, в массиве только числа. И да точно, не базы данных а таблицы.

Comment: А если у меня в таблице `base` есть колонки 'priceor' и 'pricecopy', и мне надо в зависимости от значений в массиве записывать сумму (sum) и цены (prices) в соответствующие ячейки, как мне это сделать? 
Пробовал так:
foreach ($_POST['osel'] as $itemq) {
                                if ($itemq == 0) {
                                    $quals = 'priceor';
                                }
                                else if ($itemq == 1) {
                                    $quals = 'pricecopy';
                                }
                            }
но не получается

Comment: И вместо SUM(`price`) AS `sum` FROM `ord`, я написал SUM(`$quals`) AS `sum` FROM `base`

Comment: не получается, можешь оставить контакты свои?

Comment: надо же брать значения с таблицы base, а она даже не упоминается